# not able to access a function accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular js and i have created an accordion in a td however i am not able to call a method on the click of button in the accordion. I am not able to understand the scope of the method in accordion.

```
        <tr>
            <!--Request Type-->
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="quoteType" ng-class="{required:!quoteRequest.type}" required translate>quoteNew.request.type</label>
                <select style="margin-left: 34px" id="quoteType" ng-class="{dropdowWithLongDataRequestType:isBrowserIE()}" ng-model="quoteRequest.type"
                        ng-options="type.typeId as type.typeLabel for type in types"
                        ng-change="quoteRequestTypeChange()"
                        name="requestType"
                        required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
                <p style="padding-left: 250px" ng-show="requestTypeForm.requestType.$invalid && (nextClicked || saveClicked)" class="formError" translate>form.mandatory</p>
             <button class="bouton_action" type="button" ng-click="sayHello('quoteType')"
        ng-class="{bouton_action_pushed:inProgress.save}" ng-disabled='inProgress.save' translate>
    button.save
</button>
         <div accordion-group="" ng-init="status = {isOpen: false}" is-open="status.isOpen">
  <div accordion-heading="">
      <div ng-class="{'is-open': status.isOpen}"><img src= "../../../img/icones/add.png"></div>
  </div>
  <textarea rows="2" cols="3" ng-model="{{quoteRequest.type}}"></textarea>
   <button class="bouton_action" type="button" onclick="sayHello('quoteType')"
        ng-class="{bouton_action_pushed:inProgress.save}" ng-disabled='inProgress.save' translate>
  button.save
</button>
```

sayHello() gets called outside accordion. But inside accordion it does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
onclick="sayHello('quoteType')"
```

to

```
ng-click="sayHello('quoteType')"
```

Comment: @simba give me team viewer